# pyspark f string not ending

Tags: python, pyspark, syntax-highlighting

As given in the picture this string is not ending in Jupyter notebook. But it works in python file. Why is that?

```
spark_session.sql(f"show tables in {schemaName} like '{tableName}'").count() == 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Try swapping the single and double quotes, i.e. `f'show tables in {schemaName} like "{tableName}"'`

Comment: Just tried in vs code with jupyter plugin, Databricks, and google colab and it all looks good to me. Something is funky in your ide.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to resolve the f-string in a variable, and then pass that to the sql method.

Comment: This looks like a syntax highlighter bug.